# InstallShield Change Company Name

Tags: installshield, installshield-2011

I'm using InstallShield Professional v.11 and I need to make multiple installation packages where the only difference is the company name (which changes the default install location, and the location of the start menu shortcuts).  How do I do this?
thanks,
John.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use InstallShield's Automation Interface. CompanyName is one of the items you can access/set.

From IS2010:

```
' create the automation object
Set m_ISWiProject = CreateObject("IswiAuto16.ISWiProject")
' I think for IS11 it's IswiAuto11; check your Help

' Build path to the .ism file 
strFile = "C:\<WindowsFolder>\Profiles\<UserName>\Personal\MySetups\Test.ism" 
m_ISWiProject.OpenProject strFile
m_ISWiProject.CompanyName="<Company Name>"
```

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean by the automation Interface.  I never used IS2010

Comment: I just mention IS2010 because the sample code I posted is from it. The Automation Interface allows you to create programs that change the IS project file without you having to open & edit them.  The sample and the script files I use are written in VBScript. The Help file included with your IS installation should have a chapter titled "Automating Build Processes" or something like that. There is a reference to elements you can affect and sample scripts for several situations; you can tweak those to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You might try a [project template](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield17helplib/IHelpTemplates.htm):

> A project template (.ist file) contains all of the default settings
>   and design elements that you want to use as a starting point when you
>   create an installation project or merge module project.

You could create new projects for the different companies based on the same template, but changing the company name.

[Creating Project Templates](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield17helplib/IHelpTemplatesCreate.htm)
[Basing New Projects on Templates](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield17helplib/IHelpTemplatesNewProject.htm)

Comment: I don't think this will work for me, because I want to have 1 project that has multiple releases, the difference between each release is the company name